# How to create a lockscreen

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am developing a game like angry birds in which I'm using a lock screen in which first round is by default open to play but another 9 rounds are locked now I want to know how to create an activity to unlock these rounds when completing rounds.

I have decided to use Shared Preferences but in my case shared preference some times works and sometimes not.

means that sometime I found lock open for next round and rarely...

```
if (mScore >= 90) {
    sharedpref();       
}

public void sharedpref() {
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

   Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putString("key", "5");
   editor.commit(); 
}
```

in another activity:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = settings.getString("key", "");
    Button i2;
    if(value=="5") {
        i2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockopen);      
    } 
    else {
        i2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockclose);
    }
```

Comment: Probably `value.equals("5")`?

Comment: @raj i think you should call it something else other than "lock screen" , as it's usually something else - what you see when you turn on the screen of the device. you probably mean "locked game stage" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

as solution given by johnchen902

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
  String value = settings.getString("key", "");
  Button i2;
   if(value.equals("5")){
    i2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockopen);

}else{
i2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockclose);
 }
```

is working fine now

in place of

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = settings.getString("key", "");
  Button i2;
if(value=="5"){
    i2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockopen);

}else{
i2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockclose);
}
```